# How would I access subviews in CNContactViewController?

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, contacts, cncontactviewcontroller

How would I access the subviews in CNContactViewController. I know they are properties of the UIView instance in CNContactViewController, since CNContactViewController inherits from UIViewController.

Here is my code:

```
print("subviews count: \(self.contactViewController.view.subviews.count)")
```

Here is the result in debug window:

```
subviews count: 0
```

Comment: When are you calling this code? Are you calling it after the contact VC is visible? Why not use Xcode's View Hierarchy debugger to see the layout?

Comment: It’s possible that the contact view controller is out-of-process for privacy reasons and your app won’t be able to see its subviews.